# Using Quartus from command line

Tags: verilog, fpga, intel-fpga

I am trying to use Quartus II 13.0 (Free Web Package) on Linux (Kubuntu 12.04 LTS) from the command line to generate Verilog technology netlists from Verilog RTL. I need this for a project where I compare the synthesis results produced by different tools for thousands of generated Verilog files. So using the GUI is not really an option..

For example with Xilinx Vivado I can do that using the following TCL commands:

```
read_verilog input.v
synth_design -part xc7k70t -top top_module
write_verilog output.v
```

Most ASIC tools I have worked with provide similar interfaces.

With Xilinx XST it is a bit more complicated:

1.) generation of a work.xst file:

```
run -ifn work.prj ..some..more..options..
```

2.) generation of a work.prj file:

```
verilog work "input.v"
```

3.) running synthesis:

```
xst -ifn work.xst
```

4.) generating verilog netlist from verilog binary:

```
netgen -w -ofmt verilog work.ngc output
```

But with Quartus II I can't find any documentation at all on how to use the command line tools. All I can find is documentation to the graphical IDE interface. Maybe I'm just looking in the wrong places?

So before I start poking the Quartus II IDE with strace and similar tools: Is anyone using Quartus II from the command line and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think the documentation you're looking for is: http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/qts/qts_qii52003.pdf and http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/qts/qts_qii52002.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very well hidden - Quartus-II Handbook Version 13.0, page 2-10 (or search ASSIGNMENT_FILES) - produces one example Makefile. It seems to have bit-rot - I've removed the ASSIGNMENT_FILES stuff, and the stamps are redundant (you can check for logfiles), but it's a start, and the basic structure works.

Comment: Just found this, which (surprisingly) dumps out the example makefile: `quartus_map --help=makefiles`

Comment: 'Help unavailable for option or topic "makefiles"' - Version 20.1.0 Build 711 06/05/2020 SJ Lite Edition on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

For example the following shell script synthesizes the module `binary_ops_00000000` from the design file `binary_ops_00000000.v`:

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/altera/13.0/quartus/bin
quartus_map binary_ops_00000000 --source=binary_ops_00000000.v --family="Cyclone III" 
quartus_fit binary_ops_00000000
quartus_eda binary_ops_00000000 --formal_verification --tool=conformal
cp -v fv/conformal/binary_ops_00000000.vo output.v
```

`quartus_eda` supports a wide range of differend modes (see `quartus_eda --help=tool` for a table). The Verilog generated for Conformal LEC looks fine for my purpose.

I'd recommend running this commands in an otherwise empty directory, as they generate a bunch of files and in some cases print error messages if files from previous runs (with different setting) are found.

Answer (score 3):

You can find helpful Quartus II Tcl Examples page on [intel.com](https://www.intel.com/content/altera-www/global/en_us/index/support/support-resources/design-examples/design-software/tcl.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following to get help on both all command-line arguments and Tcl functions

```
quartus_sh --qhelp
```